# Is the gradient of a vector valued real function a second order tensor?

Tags: calculus

If the function in $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto V$, where $V$ is an Euclidean vector space, is differentiable, its gradient is a second order tensor? What is the definition of $\nabla f(x)$ ?

Comment: What you have defined is a function whose image is curve in $V$ and hence it's a one variable function since its domain is $\mathbb{R}$. I suppose what you really meant is a function $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, I mean a function with scalar domain whose values are vectors. That is, $f(\alpha)=\vec{v}$. My question is: if $\nabla f(\alpha)$ is a tensor, how do I obtain it?

Comment: What you call the gradient of $f$ is really just the derivative of a single variable function. To obtain it just derive each component of $f$. Usually when we say the gradient of something we mean that something to be a multivariable function hence my first comment. But if you really meant for $f$ to be 1-variable function then its "gradient" is just the derivative of its component functions (each of which is a one variable function).